# Visual Studio use regular expressions find text between script tags

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015, find

We have tryied all possible ways,
Can you please help us to find text like [**"@Model.** or **'@Model.**] between script tags

Visual studio use regular expressions find text between script tags

But we have tried with following Regex to find tags only,

```
<script[\r\s\S]+\s*(.+?)\s*</script>
```

[VS 2015 Regex Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev14IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vs.netregularexpressionhelp);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.6.1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019)

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Like `<script(?:(?!</?script)[\r\s\S])*(?:\["@Model\.|'@Model\.])(?:(?!</?script)[\r\s\S])*</script>` https://regex101.com/r/7xfGFZ/1 ?

Comment: @the-fourth-bird: Bro thanks for support. Working fine in Website. Visual studio has some issue in finding. <script(?:(?!</?script)[\r\s\S])*(?:\"@Model\.|'@Model\.])(?:(?!</?script)[\r\s\S])*</script>

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev14IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vs.netregularexpressionhelp);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.6.1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019

Comment: There should be an extra escept for the closing bracket `<script(?:(?!</?script)[\r\s\S])*(?:\["@Model\.|'@Model\.\])(?:(?!</?script)[\r\s\S])*</script>`

Comment: @the-fourth-bird: Yes Bro tried with above option also same issue. Bro updated question with VS 2015 Help Link

Comment: I get these results https://imgur.com/a/FQmNF9Y

Comment: @the-fourth-bird: Thanks Bro, In Organization this site is block. i will check this in mobile bro

Comment: You might also try using an inline modifier to make the dot match a newline `(?s)<script(?:(?!</?script).)*(?:\["@Model\.|'@Model\.\])(?:(?!</?script).)*</script>` https://regex101.com/r/JDEfqG/1

Comment: Did it work out?